# Faulty ProcessStartInfo & Process.Start? (properly debugging?)

Tags: c#, process.start, processstartinfo

The question mainly is in the Read() method.

```
public static void Read(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    serverID = File.ReadAllText(sidname);
    Console.WriteLine("Current ID: " + serverID);
    if (serverID != oldserverID && serverID != "default" && serverID != "")
    {
        ProcessStartInfo servqueued = new ProcessStartInfo();
        servqueued.Arguments = ramlimit + " " + spname + " " + sidname + " " + resourcetxt + " " + ramoutput + " " + rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + " " + makeserverpath + " " + Logpath + " " + servqueuepath;
        servqueued.FileName = fileservepath;
        servqueued.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        servqueued.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process queue;
        queue = Process.Start(servqueued);
        Console.WriteLine("Server process queued with server name: " + serverID);
        File.AppendAllLines(logpath, new string[] { DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + ": ", "Server process queued with server name " + serverID });
        oldserverID = serverID;
    }
}
```

Not sure why the Process.Start is ignored. The rest of the clause is fine, such as, if I put the oldserverID in the beginning.

**EDIT**

The arguments are global variables, and defined earlier in the script.

**EDIT**

Here are the global variables that are referenced. Mind the path hardcoding.

```
rootpath = "%USERPROFILE%" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +"desktop" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "TerrariaServer" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "filebin";
logpath = rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "fr_log.txt";
servqueuepath = rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "queuecheck.txt";
spname = "serverparams.cmd";
sidname = "serverid.cmd";
resourcetxt = rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "ramcheck.txt";
ramoutput = rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "sysresourceoutput.exe";
makeserverpath = rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "update.bat";
Logpath = rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "fsrv_log.txt";
fileservepath = rootpath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "FileServe.exe";
```

**UPDATE**

Through the use of proper debugging methods (below), the problem source was.. solved, title edited.

Comment: The old problem was having the shell called, but that has been taken care of.. for another instance. The whole script is here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d88cf3b-89b7-4c45-bdfa-ba5ba52acdfa/a-program-that-compares-two-id-and-does-something-when-they-are-different-faulty-processstart?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Are you sure its being ignored and not just erroring out?  Also, the ProcessStartInfo may not have the same context as when you run this from the command line, so are you providing the full path.  Seeing those other variables would help.

Comment: Perhaps the path should simply be the file name, as that was the error in two previous circumstances, and they share the same directory (-- no, that is not the case). The variables have been included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't a try/catch clause upwards a little bit that could be swallowing an exception?

There is no way Process.Start is just being *"Ignored"*. Code is either not reaching it, or its executing, but just not as you'd expect.

There are a few things I'd suggest, set a breakpoint on the first line of the method, and step through the rest of it and watch what is happening - specifically in the locals/watch window. The other thing, would be to break on completion and use intellisense to look and see if there were any other swallowed exceptions in the framework or in your code.

Comment: Okay, oldserverID re-corrected using breakpoints. I will see what happens with intellisense.

Comment: Okay, the logpath was broken. It needed the file name, not the direct path.